# How to remove newline from string

Tags: java

My application flow is like i need to create a fixed length message and send it to end consumer over mqs.

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

Needs to be converted to `AAABBBCCCDDD` and send to end application over mqs
for this i am using below code

```
String response = "AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD";
response.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "");
response = AAABBBCCCDDD
```

Everything is good so far, but when the message reach to end system they are complaining about a space after each line and when checked via hex it looks like a 0D character is getting inserted at place of next line

**AAA BBB CCC DDD** -> This is how they are received

**AAA0DBBB0DCCC0DDDD** -> Hex enabled Hex’0D’ (I think it’s more like delimiter, EOL or something)

Can someone suggest how can i get rid of these characters which are getting added?

Comment: How is the string being generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASCII code `0x0d` is `CR` (Carriage Return).

When a string includes `CR+LF`s as line separators (e.g. on Windows) and your system uses `LF`s as line separators (e.g. on Unix descendants), `System.getProperty("line.separator")` just gives you `LF`. So your code removes only `LF`s let alone `CR`s.

If you just get rid of `CR` or `LF`, below may be sufficient.

```
response.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]", "");
```

Comment: Thanks @hata i tried like ```responseTransactions.replaceAll("\r?\n", "");``` this works for me and the end systems have confirmed that now they are not receiving any spaces or 0D in the message. Many thanks for the explanation as well.

Comment: @Trups You can remove the escapes from the backslashes in this answer. Or more than halve the regex length by doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70966379/256196).

Comment: You can't always presume that the newline characters are a certain character sequence. It depends on what code generated them. Bohemian's answer is safer, imho.

Answer (score 2):

Use the *any linebreak* regex `\R`:

```
response.replaceAll("\\R", "");
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#any_unicode_linebreak):

> `\R` Any Unicode linebreak sequence, is equivalent to
> `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the whitespace separators in your input, retaining all non whitespace characters, then a simple replace all should suffice:

```java
String response = "AAA\nBBB\nCCC\nDDD";
String output = response.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
System.out.println(output); // AAABBBCCCDDD
```

Answer (score 0):

`responseTransactions.replaceAll("\r?\n", "");` this worked for me and the end systems have also confirmed that now they are not receiving any spaces or 0D in the message.